# The button is not placed as I want

Tags: bootstrap-4

I would really like to get the same result.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmj78.png)

My problem is that the button is not placed correctly to the right.

Now if I add this line in CSS, it works but the code is not clean. Do you have a boostrap solution?

```
<div class="col-4 my-2 text-end ">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="home-content container" *ngIf="details">
    <div class="row pt-5 pb-3">
        <div class="col-8 my-2">
            <h2 class="ms-2">Page de signalétique</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 my-2 text-end " >
            <button type="button" (click)="goBack()" class="btn btn-primary ">Retour</button>
        </div>
        <hr class="ms-4 mt-1 mb-3" style="width: 94%">

    </div>


    <div class="row pt-3 container">
        <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <table class="table table-hover table-striped" style="width: 150%;">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Ticker</th>
                                    <td> Element</td>
                                </tr>
                               
                            </tbody>
                        </table>


                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="btn-group-vertical float-end" style="width: 45%">
                      

                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Eric, what do you mean by "the code is not clean"? Using, `<div class="col-4 my-2 text-end ">`, IS a bootstrap solution.

Comment: @Konstantinos Gallis: Hello, I want to avoid using CSS, the button is not on the right as I want.

Answer (score -1):

Proper Bootstrap Class is 'text-right', But you can achieve this by using the flex concept of bootstrap